# Python - Check if element is in 1 or more nested lists and return whole list if TRUE

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

Thanks in advance for any help.

**I have a nested list/list of lists and I need to return each list to the screen ONLY if the list contains a specific element.**

The list characteristic:

- Each list has the same amount of elements,
- Each element represents the same thing
- In the below example `index 0 = fruit name, index 1 = amount, index 2 = colour`.
- Example: `lists = [banana, 10, yellow], [apple, 12, red], [pear, 60, green], [mango, 5, yellow]`

I have played around with conditional for loops and with the idea of just creating a new list for each variation but that seems like a hard to manage solution.

Can anyone help?

Search 1:
If 'banana' is in one or more nested lists
Then print each nested list

Expected output:
[banana, 10, yellow]

Search 2:
If 'yellow' is in one or more nested lists
Then print each nested list

Expected output:
[banana, 10, yellow]
[mango, 5, yellow]

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough way to do it:

```
lists = [
    ["banana", 10, "yellow"], 
    ["apple", 12, "red"], 
    ["pear", 60, "green"], 
    ["mango", 5, "yellow"],
]

keyword = 'banana'
for lst in lists:
    if keyword in lst:
        print(lst)

keyword = 'yellow'
for lst in lists:
    if keyword in lst:
        print(lst)
```

Ideally you would extract the search to a function accepting the lists and the keyword:

```
def get_sublists_containing_keyword(lists, keyword):
    sublists = []
    for lst in lists:
        if keyword in lst:
            sublists.append(lst)
    return sublists

lists = [
    ["banana", 10, "yellow"], 
    ["apple", 12, "red"], 
    ["pear", 60, "green"], 
    ["mango", 5, "yellow"],
]

banana_lists = get_sublists_containing_keyword(lists, 'banana')
yellow_lists = get_sublists_containing_keyword(lists, 'yellow')

for banana_list in banana_lists:
    print(banana_list)
for yellow_list in yellow_lists:
    print(yellow_list)
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked a treat. I was so close in previous attempts and getting this but got my variables and searches mixed up.
I already have a function created to accept the keyword so this part was done. 
Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JoRobbertsen ,If the answer helped you , you can accept it using the tick button.

Comment: @JoRobbertsen happy to help! As Faraaz mentioned, feel free to accept my answer if you like it!

Comment: @barciewicz thank you! I’m new to Stack so wasn’t aware of this part. Have accepted the answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single liner solution for this.

```py
def search(lists, item):
    return list(filter(None, map(lambda x: x if item in x else [], lists)))
```

Now you can call the function and check it.

```py
In [12]: lists
Out[12]: 
[['banana', 10, 'yellow'],
 ['apple', 12, 'red'],
 ['pear', 60, 'green'],
 ['mango', 5, 'yellow']]

In [13]: search(lists, 'banana')
Out[13]: [['banana', 10, 'yellow']]

In [14]: search(lists, 'yellow')
Out[14]: [['banana', 10, 'yellow'], ['mango', 5, 'yellow']]
```

#### Code explanation

Here I Have used lambda expression and checked if the tobe search item is inside the list then return that list else return an empty list. And removed all the empty lists via a filter Function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) inside a **[`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)** to remove the single quote characters around the string elements when you print:

```
def print_lists_that_contain_search_term(lists: list[list[str | int]], 
                                         search_term: str) -> None:
    print(f'{search_term = }')
    print(' '.join(f'[{", ".join(map(str, lst))}]' for lst in lists if search_term in lst))

def main() -> None:
    lists = [['banana', 10, 'yellow'], ['apple', 12, 'red'], ['pear', 60, 'green'], ['mango', 5, 'yellow']]
    print_lists_that_contain_search_term(lists, 'banana')
    print_lists_that_contain_search_term(lists, 'yellow')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
search_term = 'banana'
[banana, 10, yellow]
search_term = 'yellow'
[banana, 10, yellow] [mango, 5, yellow]
```